# MVC 4 ActionLink with alt text for background image

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

In my view I have this link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", null, null, new { @class = "Edit" })
```

My Edit css class:

```
.Edit
{
    background: url("../Images/Edit.png") no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Works fine, but I want to display "Edit" when the user hovers the link as alt text.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: although there are probably ways to achieve this through some hackery, im in agreance with http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200905/css_background_images_cannot_and_should_not_have_alternate_text/ if you require alt text the image should be loaded with an image tag <img src="" alt="" etc /> in case you HAVE to have alt text on a background image a quick google yielded numerous results http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute

Comment: Not that it has to do anything with your question, but I suggest you put the text "edit" in the link (1st argument of Actionlink) and the add "text-indent: -9000px;" to the style. This way a screen reader or search engine can also see the text of your link, but it won't appear on the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try add `title` attribute for your link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", null, null, new { @class = "Edit", title="Edit" })
```