# How to style an image's alt attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display the (outer)html of an `img` tag, but I want the `alt` attribute to be in red.

The way I get the string:

```
var img_outerHTML = img[0].outerHTML;
```

This gives me the string:

`<img alt="main-logo" src="main-logo.png">`

So how can I have `main-logo` to be red?
Thank you!

**EDIT**

Thanks to `techfoobar` for the solution and everyone else that helped!
Here is a [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n7xX8/).

Comment: You'll need a plugin for that, the alt tag is rendered by the browser and cannot be changed by html / css alone.

Comment: @Matthew, Thank you. Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: @m.spyratos read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean by "display the outer HTML?" What's going to show in the user? Interpreted markup, or literally the characters `<img alt="main-logo" src="main-logo.png">`?

Comment: Alt acts like a tooltip and it uses browser's default

Comment: what do you mean you want it in red? How are you displaying it?

Comment: @MattBall, I will display literally the characters `<img alt="main-logo" src="main-logo.png">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are *trying to display the outer HTML as such in another element*, you can do:

```
var s = '<img alt="main-logo" src="main-logo.png">';
// As pointed out by user bfavaretto, we need to html-encode it before
// injecting the <span>
s = $('<div/>').text(s).html();
s = s.replace(/alt=\"([a-zA-Z0-9\s-]*)\"/, 'alt="<span class=\'red\'>$1</span>"');
```

Once done, this will transform the HTML string to (Note: that everything other that the span will be HTML encoded. Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/921204)

```
<img alt="<span class='red'>main-logo</span>" src="main-logo.png">
```

Actually, it will be:

```
&lt;img alt="<span class='red'>main-logo</span>" src="main-logo.png"&gt;
```

And in your CSS, add:

```
span.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I +1ed this, but the reg exp probably could use some work since it is really limited to what can be in the value.

Comment: Yes, especially the `[a-z0-9\s-]*` bit.

Comment: @techfoobar, That was my very first thought. I tried it, but it actually displays this: `<img alt="<span class='red'>main-logo</span>" src="main-logo.png">`. So it doesn't add the `span` as `html`, but as a string.

Comment: A small problem the user will probably face: the img outerHTML will have to be html-encoded before the replace, so when it's displayed in a container, only the injected span will be parsed as actual tags.

Comment: @bfavaretto - That is a huge problem. This wont work directly! You're totally right. Din think of that.

Comment: Made some mods to take html-encoding into account. Credit: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/921204][1]

Comment: @techfoobar, Thank you very much! That was a really big help! :)

Answer (score -1):

This can also be done by CSS only.

just wrap yout img tag into span tag and apply red color to that span.
try this

```
<span style="color: red;"><img alt="main-logo" src="main-logo.png"></span>
```