# How to add text using css in textarea?

Tags: css

I am adding image using following css

```
{
    background-image: url(../images/icon_new_reset.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Then how to give alternate text or add text over `background image`.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do this. The `alt` attribute is only for the `<img>` tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css background image alt attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute)

Comment: I am very curious as to why you want to do this. I know alt text is good for: search engine bots, usability for people with disabilities, users with extremely bad internet connection/offline browsing of cache content. how does the background image alt text help with any of these? being the background it's not content. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `textarea` you can't add text with `css`

but if you use `div` or ... you can add text using this:

```
<div class="testDiv"></div>
```

your style is like this:

```
.testDiv:after{
   content: "your text";
}
```

by the way it's better use `javascript` or `jquery` for changing value or text.