# Add background image using php

Tags: php, wordpress, image, background, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using wordpress and ACF plugins to add an image :

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

I would like to add an image in a div as a background.
I used this code in my style.css but it doesn't work :

```
background-image: url(<?php $image = get_field('image_projet');?> <img 

src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />);
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: you're adding html to the css file.

Comment: You cannot use PHP code inside a CSS file, you can do it within an inline css code(style tags), which is still not a best practice,..can you please elaborate your question a bit more, the code snippet is not very clear

Comment: <? is not recognized inside the double quotation

Comment: What do you try to tell us with the code fragment given? Is this supposed to be a CSS file? HTML? PHP? Why do you mix CSS with html? You're not echoing anything in the CSS part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A css file contains CSS. Just CSS. You can't write html or PHP into a CSS file.
If you want to generate a CSS property with PHP, you must use the `<style>...</style>` tags directly in your PHP file (the view). For instance :

```
<?php $image = get_field('image_projet'); // fetch the ACF field ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page's Title</title>
        <style>
            .your-div {
                background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>');
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- this div uses the $image URL as a background. -->
        <div class="your-div">
            Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, the image in background works, but i have the same images for all articles ! Each article have one unique image.
I tried this code :   background-image: url('<?php echo $image['url']; echo $image['alt']; ?>'); but it doesn't work. I need the "$image['alt']; "

Answer (score 0):

do it this way , you can't add alt via css so use title instead, look [here, SO css background image alt attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute)

```
`<div style="background-image: url( <?php echo $image['url']; ?>); height: 200px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;" title= "<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">my DIV  with a background image:</div>
```