# CSS or Javascript - display fallback text if background image not loaded

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, onerror

How can I display text instead of logo, if the logo graphic file isn't loaded or missing? I have div with background PNG image:

```
<div class="iHaveBgImage">
this text should be displayed if bg image is not loaded
</div>

.iHaveBgImage { background-image: url('img.png') }
```

It doesn't have to be pure CSS, Javascript solution is allowed. I was thinking of onerror event, but it works with images, not elements that have image backgrounds.

EDIT:
I was told this has been answered before, but there is another situation. I didn't say one can alter DOM, only apply CSS and JS. Second, in that other solution is sugested I should use title attribute and I tried it and it doesn't display text, only hovers it.

Comment: No, it's not duplicate. I didn't say one can alter DOM, only apply CSS and JS. Second, in that solution is sugested to use title attribute and I tried it and it doesn't display text, only hovers it.

Comment: ok, check my answer I have suggested an alternative using span.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it this way:

**HTML**

```
<div class="iHaveBgImage">
  <p>this text should be displayed if bg image is not loaded</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.iHaveBgImage { background-image:
url('https://s31.postimg.org/yqv51r5xn/6936671_hd_wallpapers_for_ipad.jpg');
color:red;
}

.iHaveBgImage > p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Works perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/s0gt2eng/

Comment: Your solution does not work if the image has transparency

Comment: @ManuelFerreiro This solution was given in direct response to the OP whose question did not include opacity or transparency.

Comment: @ManuelFerreiro If you need to use an image with opacity, consider using an <img> tag and then use the onerror event to display the text whenever the image does not load.

Answer (score 3):

**This is what I suggested in the [duplicate tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute):**

```css
.iHaveBgImage{
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background-image: url('http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-5.jpg');
  }
```

```html
<div class="iHaveBgImage" title="this text should be displayed if bg image is not loaded">
</div>
```

**Alternative using span tags:**

```css
span.image:before{
  content:" "; background:url('http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-5.jpg');
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
  <span class="image">alternate text</span>
```

Comment: I tried first solution with title attribute, but the fallback text doesn't show, only tooltip.

Comment: As for second solution, what happens if the image is smaller than fallback text?

Comment: @Dalibor Its obvious the text will be seen if the image is smaller. Use js to hide and show text onerror.

Answer (score -1):

One workaround to this would be to change

```
<div class="iHaveBgImage">
this text should be displayed if bg image is not loaded
</div>

.iHaveBgImage { background-image: url('img.png') }
```

To :

```
<img src="img.png" alt="Seems like this image failed to load" />
```

Alternatively I am not sure if the following would work, but you can MAYBE do something along the lines of:

```
<img class="iHaveBgImage" alt="Seems like this image failed to load" />

.iHaveBgImage { background-image: url('img.png') }
```

**EDIT:** Something that just popped up in my head that could possibly also work would be to have:

```
<div class="iHaveBgImage">
<p class="bgText">this text should be displayed if bg image is not loaded</p>
</div>

.iHaveBgImage { 
background-image: url('img.png') 
}
.bgText {
  z-index: -9999;
}
```

Comment: The first solution won't work without altering DOM (only CSS and JS). The latter won't work because I don't use position absolute and I don't want to because all is aligned as it should be.

Comment: Alright! Fair enough. Still, if you want one function, you must be ready to, eventually, sacrifice another (or atleast, re-do a previous one). I am guessing you already know this, but wanted to get that out there :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
P.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.iHaveBgImage {
  background-image: url('https://s31.postimg.org/yqv51r5xn/6936671_hd_wallpapers_for_ipad.jpg');
  color: red;
width:700px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="iHaveBgImage">
   <p class="hidden> This text should be displayed if bg image is not loaded</p>
</div>
```

if you want to use  text visible to text use `<span></span>` tag and create css `span {display: block;}` or

**html**

```
 <p class="hidden> This text should be displayed if bg image is not loaded</p>
```

**CSS**

```
P.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: And how will the span be made visible if the image can't be loaded?

Comment: updated my answer, look at this

Comment: Its displayed even when the image is loaded.

Comment: what do you mean(when the image is loaded)not clear your question

Comment: In your solution, both text and image are visible. Text should be visible only if the image is not loaded or doesn't exist.

Comment: use width and height https://fiddle.jshell.net/t4pj9et4/1/

Comment: Your output: [Text is displayed](http://i.imgur.com/VL2IWwe.png?1)

Comment: @AniMenon now its fine,

Comment: @Codeone If you hide it, then it will never be displayed even when the image is not displayed.

Comment: he sayed  `Text should be visible only `  i used  `span` tag but his not accepted the answer