# How can I use CSS for a responsive site, but still provide ALT text on images so my site is accessible?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a site with an image at the top of the page. The site is fully responsive.

For the desktop view, I have a specific image I load for the header on the site. For the mobile view, I have a different image.

In the CSS, I use something like:

```
 .headerimage { background:url(/images/header-desktop.png) no-repeat top left; }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .headerimage { background:url(/images/header-mobile.png) no-repeat top left; }
 }
```

And in the HTML it's just `<div class='headerimage'></div>`

My question is: how can I add ALT text (like I would to an IMG) tag so my site is fully accessible for screen readers, I get the SEO benefits of alt text, etc.? Obviously I can switch to using an IMG tag but that would require some serious hacks to keep it responsive once I have two IMG tags to deal with.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture (but there must be a question I can mark this as a duplicate of)

Comment: data-attributes.....Or just invisible text.

Comment: @Paulie_D — Data attributes do nothing by themselves. Invisible text is awful (and tends to be invisible to screen readers which is most of the point of alt attributes).

Comment: By invisible I just meant *unseen*....there are several methods available - http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/ One of these should work.

Comment: … and, surprisingly, I can't find a duplicate.

Comment: Don't think there is away using background image to add alt text. An option would be using the title attribute on the containing div <div class="headerimage" title=""></div>. Title in modern browsers seems to function the same as alt

Answer (score 5):

HTML 5 introduces [the picture element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) which allows you to specify a series of images with media queries.

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="/images/header-mobile.png" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)">
 <img src="/images/header-desktop.png" alt="Foo">
</picture>
```

Comment: <picture> element currently only supported natively by the latest Chrome, Opera & Chrome for Android (with support in Firefox in development) with no guarantee that it will be widely adopted by other browsers in future

Comment: @rJ7 — That's wrong (and contradicts the information in the link I provided), it's supported by all in-development browsers except Opera Mini (which will take the `<img>` element as a fallback). http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture

Comment: thanks mate, I just now knew about this picture element while search about this I found this Cons

Answer (score -1):

You can't without resorting to Javascript AFAIK.

Using only CSS, your best option to have some description of the background image in your code is to use the title attribute in the DIV tag.

See here :

[CSS background image alt attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute)

[CSS or Javascript - display fallback text if background image not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917418/css-or-javascript-display-fallback-text-if-background-image-not-loaded/37918621#37918621)

Answer (score -1):

Add a broken image, a hack.

Pseudo elements work for broken images. [Read here](https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/)

Use the pseudo elements to show other images on breakpoints.

```
img::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('http://lorempizza.com/200/200');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  img::before {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200X200')
  }
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xcsoby7f/1/)**