# How to prevent showing image alt text if image is loaded using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am loading an image through css `background` property , instead of using `src` attribute. But in that case the `alt` text is also showing up. How can I stop showing `alt` text & show it only if image is not loaded

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 82px;
  background-size: 200px 82px;
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJr81CRJeZGFiBsA9_AOyyxegiIPctdcbNfHThnpnclmFH-mJwoQ");
}
```

```html
<img class="test" alt="My background image">
```

Comment: Try to use div tags other than img tag to avoid showing alt text. Better to use img tag incase of image failure...

Comment: Check the answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute

Comment: @brk Could you tagged jquery in your question?

Comment: @brk, If an image is loaded or not, you can check it with image `naturalHeight` and `naturalWeight`. but if your url is invalid then it also returned a image with 1px dot `(1x1)` [for only your image hosting url]. So you should check if the image `naturalHeight` is greater than 1 for image loaded properly.Then you can removed alt attribute value. See the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ataur63/4w5aywzc/

Comment: `naturalWeight` should be `naturalWidth`. My mistake in typo. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do a little trick and hide the "text" inside the image if the image has no `src` attribute (or its empty).

(You can hide the text in many ways I choose one)

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 82px;
  background-size: 200px 82px;
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJr81CRJeZGFiBsA9_AOyyxegiIPctdcbNfHThnpnclmFH-mJwoQ");
}

img:not([src]) {
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

img:not([src]):after {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: attr(alt);
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<img class="test" alt="My background image">
```

<sub>The completion for the css (the `:after` part) received from [@Ihazkode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8157693/i-haz-kode).</sub>

For displaying the `alt` after the image loading you can load (with javascript) the image first, then, put it in the image and display the `alt`. (Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/863110) answer)

```js
$('[data-image]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var alt = $this.attr('alt');
  var src = $(this).attr('data-image');
  $this.removeAttr('alt');
  
  $('<img/>').attr('src', src).on('load', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    // simulate the delay for heavy image
    setTimeout(function(){
      $this.css('background', 'url(' + src + ')').attr('alt', alt);
    }, 1000);
  }).on('error', function() {
    $this.attr('alt', alt);
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 82px;
  background-size: 200px 82px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="test" alt="My background image" data-image="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJr81CRJeZGFiBsA9_AOyyxegiIPctdcbNfHThnpnclmFH-mJwoQ">
```

Comment: @Mosh Feu in this case the alt text wont be shown if image is not loaded. Here is a https://jsfiddle.net/cg6rh4Lu/1/

Comment: @Ihazkode Thanks but I think he wants to show the `alt` after the image "physically" loaded to the page.

Comment: @Ihazkode Thank for the correction. I added a on error handler which take care about it. I understand now your solution and that's nice! (and working)

Comment: @brk any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I need to know, is there any purpose of setting background image to `<img>` tag?
If yes, there is no point to use `<img>` tag here user `<div>` or any other tags instead of using `<img>`. 
As per the W3C standard  tag should contain `alt="some text"`, if `<img>` source not found.

Comment: I don't know why down voted. My comment as per the W3C standard. If you don't know about that go and read how to use HTML tags and then do code. Before that using nonstandard coding is useless and reducing your code standard.

Comment: I was the one who down-voted. I down-voted your comment because it's a comment and not an answer. Regardless of the validity of the content of your comment, it is not an answer. Please see [answer]

Comment: Its not necessary to answer for this question lol. I don't like to encourage this type of unnecessary things. We are not here to just answer the question. My point was he has to understand that what he doing is wrong and he has to understand, how to use html tags and purpose of attributes. 
First you should understand what I said before down vote.

Comment: So people like you to wait for the opportunity to down vote right. I think you are getting more reputation for down voting, enjoy your down voting. Thanks.

Comment: @PrakashS you loose rep points when you down vote. The answer section is for usefull information to solve the problem. An alternative solution to the question is fine. But your _"answer"_ is missinge the information how to add an alt text to a background image in a standard conform way if e.g. a `div` is used and how to only show it if that background image is not loaded. So if the OP would follow your advice then the problem would still be the same. If everyone would write their comments in the answer section then you have a hard time find alternative solutions in all that comments.

Comment: Let's say I use <img> tag for small thumbnail image like 20x20 px. If the image not found, my whole layout getting collapsed. If I remove alt attribute, my sonarqube friend will start shouting at me.