# Alt-Background for transparent background-image

Tags: css, http-status-code-404, background-image

I have some div's with transparent background-images. But if one image is not available, I have an empty div. You can set a second url as fallback (`background: url('content-image'), url('fallback-image');`), but the images will be stacked and both are visible, as the initial image is transparent (in my case both are transparent).
Maybe there is a way to fetch the 404 error with JS/jQuery?

Edit:
The tricky thing is, that my background-images are transparent. With fully opaque images, the technique to set multiple url() is totally find.

Edit2:

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px">
  <div style="background: url('transparent-image.png'); height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
</div>
```

If 'transparent-image.png' is not available, the div will be blank and throw 404.

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px">
  <div style="background: url('transparent-image.png'), url('fallback-image.png'); height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
</div>
```

If 'transparent-image.png' is available, it will overlay the fallback-image and I see both due to transparency.

Cheers :)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background image alt attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute)