# How to fix a Random Image Generator?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I seem to be writing a line of code wrong, how can I get this code to display in the section class of .background-image

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    var images = [],
    index = 0;
    images[0] = "<img src= 'gfx/develop-design-header-image-1.jpg' alt='Visit Computer Hope'>";
    images[1] = "<img src= 'gfx/develop-design-header-image-2.jpg' alt='Visit Computer Hope'>";
    images[2] = "<img src= 'gfx/develop-design-header-image-3.jpg' alt='Visit Computer Hope'>";
    images[3] = "<img src= 'gfx/develop-design-header-image-4.jpg' alt='Visit Computer Hope'>";
    images[4] = "<img src= 'gfx/develop-design-header-image-5.jpg' alt='Visit Computer Hope'>";
    images[5] = "<img src= 'gfx/develop-design-header-image-6.jpg' alt='Visit Computer Hope'>";
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    // document.write(images[index]);

    document.getElementsByClassName(".background-image") [0].style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[index]}')`;  

});
```

Comment: Seems like your images shouldn't be full tags but just the source if you're just using them in css: `const images[0] = "gfx/develop-design-header-image-1.jpg";`

Comment: Thanks my code above works if I comment out this line


document.getElementsByClassName(".background-image") [0].style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[index]}')`;

and add in this line  // document.write(images[index]);

Comment: Correct! There's a big difference between writing an `img` tag to the DOM and setting the background property in CSS! See my answer below for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

The background-image class only works when you put the url directly. In your code you are creating an img tag

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  "use strict";

  var images = [],
  index = 0;
  images[0] = "gfx/develop-design-header-image-1.jpg";
  images[1] = "gfx/develop-design-header-image-2.jpg";
  images[2] = "gfx/develop-design-header-image-3.jpg";
  images[3] = "gfx/develop-design-header-image-4.jpg";
  images[4] = "gfx/develop-design-header-image-5.jpg";
  images[5] = "gfx/develop-design-header-image-6.jpg";
  index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  // document.write(images[index]);

  document.getElementsByClassName(".background-image") [0].style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[index]}')`;});
```

Comment: This worked thank you, can I still add an alt tag?

Comment: Here there is an answer, you can use the title attribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute/17126523

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code with a couple things fixed:

- Your images should just reference the URL and not create HTML `img` elements
- Your `getElementsByClassName` selector should not have a `.` in it

```js
const images = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FFFF",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000"
];
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
document.getElementsByClassName("background-image") [0].style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[index]}')`;
```

```css
.background-image {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

Note that you lose the ability to add `alt` text in this case! If your images are meaningful enough to convey information, they probably should not be background images.

If you absolutely need them to be background images, you can sat the `role` attribute on the `div` to `"img"` and give it an `aria-label`. This will likely obscure any content inside that div from screen readers, so make sure you really want to go this way rather than using an `img` tag.