# How do I add alt text to images I put in the body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, bootstrap-5

I need to provide alt text for all my images, but I was not thinking about that when I put all my background images in the CSS under the body tag. The following is my my background image in my CSS that I need to add alt text to:

```
body
{
    background: url('contact.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.5), 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

For other images that I put in the CSS I have been using:

```
<span class="background-image" role="img" aria-label="Cook in the rue de Stamboul, Constantinople, Turkey"> </span>
```

However, because I am using the body tag for the other background images there is no class. Therefore, I do not know how to provide the alt text for those background images. I would really appreciate y'alls help.

Comment: I think its answered here: [CSS background image alt attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute).

Comment: If it needs an alt, it probably shouldn't be a background image. If it's an integral part of the content, it should be an `img` tag complete with `alt` attribute. If it's purely visually decorative then a background image should suffcie.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some responses on a question a bit similar to this and some people are saying that background images are used only for aesthetic purposes and don't need an alt text.

[CSS background image alt attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216035/css-background-image-alt-attribute)

Another guy suggested using the title attribute which allows the title to appear as a tool tip when the mouse is hovered over the object